# Disabling button when form is not valid

Tags: angular, ionic2

Struggling a bit with a form button not enabling when form is invalid. The button is invalid when the form is invalid but is not enabling when the form is valid(remains disabled).

Here is a basic sample of the code.

component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators  }  from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 templateUrl: 'build/pages/opportunity/opportunity.html'
})
export class OpportunityPage implements OnInit {

   public opportunityAddForm: any;
        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private _formBuilder: FormBuilder)         {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
     this.opportunityAddForm = this._formBuilder.group({
     clientEmail: ["", Validators.required],
     opportunityAdd: ["", Validators.required]
  })
 }
 submitOpportunityForm(): void {
 console.log(this.opportunityAddForm.value);
  }
 }
```

and the form

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar>
   <ion-title>
     ADD OPPORTUNITY
   </ion-title>
 </ion-navbar>
```

```
<ion-content padding class="Opportunity">
   <form  [formGroup]="opportunityAddForm" novalidate (submit)=submitOpportunityForm()>
    <ion-list>    
      <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Client email</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="email" ngControl="clientEmail" placeholder="Please add client emails"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Opportunity name</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" ngControl="opportunityAdd" placeholder="Add an opportunity name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <div padding>
    <button block [disabled]="!opportunityAddForm.valid">Add opportunity</button>
    </div>
    </ion-list>
  </form>
 </ion-content>
```

Comment: What if you replace ngControl with formControlName?

Comment: That did the job!!...thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `ngControl` with `formControlName`. Your `this.opportunityAddForm` can't find controls to validate.

**Example:**

```
<ion-input type="email" ngControl="clientEmail" placeholder="Please add client emails"></ion-input>
```

Change to:

```
<ion-input type="email" formControlName="clientEmail" placeholder="Please add client emails"></ion-input>
```